# R: Transposing a two column data table

Tags: r, data.table, transpose

I am trying to transpose a two column data table. The dt is of something like this.

```
access.id | data
    1        0
    1        0
    2       150
   ...      ...
```

What I want to have is something like this.

```
access.id | V1 | V2
    1       0    0
    2      150  ...
```

I have tried different approaches but I can't seem to get the result I want.

```
test[, lapply(.SD, .fun=function(dt) { return (transpose(dt)) }) , by = access.id]
```

or

```
test[, lapply(.SD, .fun=function(dt) { return (transpose(dt[data])) }) , by = access.id]
```

or

```
test[, .SD[, transpose(data)] , by = access.id]
```

The above give me an error: "Error in transpose(dt) : l must be a list."

```
test[, lapply(.SD, .fun=function(dt) { return (transpose(dt$data)) }) , by = access.id]
```

This gives the error: ' Error in dt$data : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"

```
test[, .SD[, t(data)] , by = access.id]
```

This works but gives me the exact same data table.

When I tried substituting t(data) for sum(data), it worked and gave me the sum of the data columns. I am unsure why what I tried doesn't work.

So my question is, how do I transpose this data table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a row id and then `dcast` using that new column as the right-hand-side of the formula.

```
df[, rid := paste0('V', rowid(access.id))]

dcast(df, access.id ~ rid, value.var = 'data')
#    access.id  V1  V2
# 1:         1   0   0
# 2:         2 150 300
```

This also works if you do it all in one step

```
dcast(df, access.id ~ paste0('V', rowid(access.id)), value.var = 'data')
```

Explanation:

`rowid` is a "Convenience function for generating a unique row ids within each group". It takes a vector `x` and creates a vector that starts at 1 and increments by 1 each time it sees that same value of `x` again, and starts over at 1 when a new value of `x` is encountered.

```
df[, rid := paste0('V', rowid(access.id))][]
#    access.id data rid
# 1:         1    0  V1
# 2:         1    0  V2
# 3:         2  150  V1
# 4:         2  300  V2
```

If the `x` is not ordered the explanation above is a little lacking, but I'm honestly not sure how to explain that situation well. Maybe this example will help.

```
data.table(c('a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a'), 
      rowid(c('a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a')))
#    V1 V2
# 1:  a  1
# 2:  a  2
# 3:  b  1
# 4:  a  3
# 5:  b  2
# 6:  b  3
# 7:  a  4
```

Since you want each row of each group as its own column, you put this new `rid` variable on the right-hand-side of the `dcast` formula. `dcast` wants you to put your desired columns on the right and the corresponding rows on the left. (not the best explanation, see `?dcast`.)

Data used

```
df <- fread('
access.id   data
    1        0
    1        0
    2       150
    2       300
')
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this part. "~ paste0('V', rowid(access.id)" I am getting the table that I want, but the data is not in the correct order. There's access.id and then V1, V10, V11, ..., V2, V20. Is there a way to correct that?

Comment: I've added an explanation for `rowid`. Not sure what's going on with your data specifically though, if you post some example data I could take a look.

Comment: The correct data appears in the correct columns. It's just that the columns appear at an unorthodox order.

Comment: It seems that the names of the columns were ordered alphabetically. I changed ~ "~ paste0('V', rowid(access.id)" to "~ rowid(access.id)" and I they are ordered numerically. Also used dcast.data.table instead of dcast. Thanks for the help.